# get Illegal host header from akka (playframework) with nginx as frontend

Tags: playframework, akka, nginx-config

I get

```
Illegal 'host' header: Invalid input ':', expected DIGIT or 'EOI' (line 1, column 4): 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl. I use nginx as frontend with ssl, the config file contains:

```
        proxy_buffering    off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        upstream my-backend {
          server localhost:9000;
        }


        location / {
          proxy_pass  http://my-backend;
          proxy_set_header Host www.example.com;
        }
```

with nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu) and play 2.7.4
I got this error after restarting nginx and play server ...
The website is no longer available
Any help or tip much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you asked Nginx to include the hostname + port to the downstream host :

proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;

IIRC, $http_host also includes the portnumber. Try changing to $host instead and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Changed localhost to from IPv6 to IPv4 address (0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 -> 127.0.0.1) in nginx.conf. Still don't know why this error now has popped up und why proxy_set_header doesn't work)